# Vue chrome extension - page_action not open popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have some trouble to use `page_action` for a chrome extension. I'm using a vue cli boilerplate to create the extension base and it's working fine if I use a standalone tab or browser action with popup. I'm trying to use page action to restrict the extension to only a ceratin website. As I read from the docs, page action have a popup like browser action and if I understand well, I can define it inside my manifest file and it's supposed to be open when I click on the extension icon.

What is happening is that if I click on the extension icon on the website where I want that extension run, my `popup.html` file will not be opened, I'm only able to see the default chrome extension popup as you can see from the screenshot.

[default popup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YApwh.png)

This is my manifest file content, I'm using `webRequest` so the background script need to be persistent:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_extName__",
  "homepage_url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "description": "A Vue Browser Extension",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "https://www.exampleurl.com/*",
    "https://*.exampleurl.net/*",
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16.png",
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "128": "icons/128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "__MSG_extName__",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/19.png",
      "38": "icons/38.png"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what I have for now inside my background.js file:

```
var streamUrl

browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( () => {
  browser.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    browser.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new browser.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'www.exampleurl.com/*', schemes: ['https']},
      })],
      actions: [new browser.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }])
  })
})

browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( (details) => {
  console.log(details)
  streamUrl = details.url
},{
  urls: ["https://*.exampleurl.net/*"],
  types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
},["responseHeaders"])

console.log(streamUrl)

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (message) => {
  console.log(message)
  if( message.type === 'ready' ){
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({url: streamUrl})
  }
})
```

Is there any fix for this? Do I miss something?

Comment: A page action popup is disabled by default. You need to enable it on supported sites explicitly, see the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:pageaction).

Comment: Then you need to show that code in your question, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've already show the code.

Comment: You didn't show the code that enables page_action. You can see an example of how to enable a page action in the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:pageaction).